# Sharepoint Instant List Filter on Specific List Fields Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, list, sharepoint, filter

I have the following part of code that is working on an instant list filter on a SharePoint List using the Content Editor Web Part. As it stands, it filters the list by comparing the user input to information in all columns in the current view of the list. I'm struggling to work out how to alter this code so that it only compares the user input to specific fields. I know this sounds similar to what the OOB list filter does, but that is not suitable for my needs.

```
input.keyup(function() // On key presses
{
    listItems.each(function() // for each items in our list
    {
    var text = $j(this).text().toLowerCase(); // get all the text values of that list item
    if (text.indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase()) != -1) // does it match the text of our filter?
{ 
         $j(this).show();// yes! show it!
    }
    else
{
         $j(this).hide(); // nope! hide it!
    }
    });
});
```

I've been working on the premise that I can alter line 6 so that I can reference the desired field as the data to compare the user input to, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It might not fit your use-case, here is an alternative  (and wacky) solution to filtering VIEWS.

[image]

**The code goes into a Calculated Column, which.. if set to datatype=Number will execute the HTML & JavaScript**

So no need to add CEWP or any other code to pages. And it works everywhere the Calculated Column is displayed in a VIEW

I added this one Calculated Column to a standard Task List on SharePoint Online. Should work on SP2010 and SP2013 as well.

It works because when the Calculated Column is displayed it adds an EventListener (**for every displayed item!**) to a parent DOM element.
*At this time the Search box itself is not loaded yet! So you can't attach the keyup event on the input tag*

When you type in the Search box the event bubbles up in the DOM and is captured by all functions.

Create a calculated column with Formula, and set the datatype to Number:

```
="<img src=_layouts/images/blank.gif onload={"
&"TR=this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;"
&"TR.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.addEventListener("
&"""keyup"
&""",(function(e){this.style.backgroundColor="""
&[Task Name]
&""".indexOf(e.srcElement.value)===-1?""lightcoral"":""lightgreen""}).bind(TR)"
&")}>"
```

The onload event on the blank IMG element is a trick to execute a function on page load; this function goes a bunch of parentNodes up (needs to go above the search DIV!) to attach those keyup events.

For every keypress in the search box the event bubbles up and **all** (item) functions are called.

Because the functions receive the scope of the TR element with *bind(TR)* the function is executed within the TR context; and all it has to do is do the comparison with what was typed in the Search box (e=event) and color  the TR (the item row)
You can replace the *.backgroundColor* part with *.display* and set the colorvalues to *none* and *initial* to show/hide Item rows.

If you want to search in all/other Columns you just replace or extend the &[Task Name]& part with the Columns you want to filter on.

*note the 2x double-quotes used for every instance where a JavaScript quote is required*

*Also note adding spaces to the Javascript will break the onload declaration because the Browser adds quotes for every non-space interrupted string*

Alas, debugging this code in a Calculated Column is a real PITA.